# Not booting when wifi is plugged in

Tags: usb, wifi, boot-issues

Everything was working fine a few months ago.
I picked up my raspberry again and wrote the new raspian image on de microsd card.

Then came the problems:
The raspberry was very slow and got several issues.
Isseus:
wpa_supplicant return code 1
And after the raspi has almost booted, it stucks at "applicable law" (last sentence).

I have changed the power supply for a better one, switched sd-card and disconnected all USB devices.

The issues appear when the USB dongle is plugged in.
The raspi is very slow now.

I don't have these issues when using openelec for example.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi b+
And a TL-WN725N V2

Edit:
I have installed the wifi drivers, no booting problems. I still have problems connecting to network

Comment: Log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2lvwvrj1lw37py/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: Dropbox gives a 404 on that link.

Answer (score 1):

If you use identical hardware with two different sets of software and one set of software works and the other does not it strongly suggests faulty software.

I suggest you make sure you have the latest version of Raspbian and then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo rpi-update`.  Perhaps this is a known issue which has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier model Pis (up to B+ even) had issues when connecting multiple USB devices. Try booting with only the wifi dongle and keyboard attached.

Also, as [@joan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13650/joan) said, first run `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo rpi-update`